# Algebraic Symbol Manipulation While Finding the Sum of a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

In a precalc text, in the chapter on geometric progressions and series, we're told of the formula

$S=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$

and that:

$S=\frac{a}{1-r}$ is valid for $|r|<1$

We're then asked to find the sum of $3+\sqrt{3}+1+...$

Literally that's all the information given, including the "...".

The text gives the answer as: $\frac{3\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{2}$ but I'm struggling to derive the calculations that get us there.

I set $a=3$ and $r = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ which, by the 2nd formula above, gives me $\frac{3}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$

I clear the radical sign in the denominator by multiplying by the conjugate:

$\frac{3}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}$ which gives me $\frac{3+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}}\Rightarrow3+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\Rightarrow...?$

It's at this point the head scratching begins.

Hints?

Comment: $3+\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}+1)$. And use parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is you should have cancelled $3$ in the numerator and denominator, so $\frac{3\sqrt3}3$ becomes $\sqrt3$.  So

$$\dfrac{3+\frac{3\sqrt3}3}{\frac23}=\frac32(3+\sqrt3)=\frac32(\sqrt3)(\sqrt3+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{3}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}&=\frac{3}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you saying I have the wrong value for $r$? That it should be $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$? If so can you help me understand why. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick $\sqrt3/3=1/\sqrt3$.

Comment: Eeesh. Of course. Thank you.